# Where should I put an application level initialization code in gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT application.

Where can I put an initialization code so it runs when the GWT `devMode` is up?

For example, I want to put `log("GWT is up...")` before everything.

I tried to put the code in a servlet, but it seems that they are executed once if it receives a request from client.

I don't want that, I want it automatically run whenever the GWT server begins running

Comment: Can you define "GWT server" ? Are you talking about RPC servlets? or GWT application(UI) as a whole?

Comment: @sanbhat RPC servlets

Comment: There is no GWT server.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ sorry, corrected

Comment: Use listeners in webapp configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GWT server.

You might talking about the whole application. In such cases Your question should contain *when the application gets deployed*.  If so write a startup servlet.

```
       <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StartUpServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>StartUpServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>xxx.server.StartUpServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
```

That servlet code run's when your application gets deployed.

And in your servlet `init()`

```
   @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        log("GWT is up...")
    }
```

Comment: `init()` gets called when the first request reaches server. So this might not be the one OP is looking for

Comment: @sanbhat Nope. `<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>`. That tells that  initialize that servlet on start up.

Comment: Or he is maybe asking for the GWT app entrypoint, *onModuleLoad* ?

Comment: @ITomas Suspected. later OP mentioned `I tried to put the code in a servlet,`

Comment: This is the correct answer and is what I am looking for.<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ one more question. Can I deploy my GWT application using devMode? I mean I don't want complicated web server applications. What I want is to package the whole thing together with the execution script like `javaw gwt-dev-mode myapplication` and send to my friend. so he can directly execute and run the application on his pc. can I do that?

Comment: You cannot. You need a web-server to serve the requests , right ?